# Euclid: What is the difference between a 'surface' and a plane 'surface'?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, soft-question, definition

I've begun to study Euclid's Elements and i've a few questions regarding the difference between a surface and plane surface.

A surface is said to be *"that which has length and breadth only"*, it then goes on to say *"a plane surface is a surface which lies evenly with the straight lines on itself"*.

What is the difference between the two? What exactly is a plane surface? Can a plane surface be curved, or is it only flat?

I apologise for being a pedant, these definitions should be straight forward but I wish they could be a bit more specific, I want a good understanding of them before I move on.

Comment: My understanding of these terms is as follows: A *surface* has two dimensions but need not be flat - e.g. **cones**, **cylinders** and **spheres** have *surfaces*. A *plane surface* is any **flat** surface which can be finite or infinite.

Answer (score 5):

The first point to make is that Euclid's definitions are not definitions in the modern sense, so that this kind of confusion is common. A surface, for Euclid, is roughly a two-manifold embedded in 3-dimensional space, e.g. the standard 2-sphere or one of its hemispheres, or the graph of certain functions from the plane to the line. A plane surface is just a surface that happens to lie in a plane, e.g. the unit disk. One more modern way to think about "lies evenly with the straight lines on itself" is that the tangent lines to a plane surface lie within the surface, as does not occur in general.

Answer (score 1):

> *What is the difference between a surface and a plane surface ?*

What is the difference between a line and a straight line ?

Comment: A line is a breadthless length, so a straight line is a kind of line. Another type of line is a curved line.

Comment: Then perhaps you could also get a curved surface ?

Comment: I imagine so, isn't that what a sphere is?

Comment: Yes, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the first definition first. When he says "has length and breadth only", he basically means the same as when a differential geometer defines a 2-manifold. There are at each point two degrees of freedom for movement within the surface itself. For instance, the surface of the earth can be thought of as only having length and breadth (longitude and latitude is mostly enough to specify any point on the planet).

As for when he says "lies evenly with all the lines on itself", he probably means that plane surfaces are convex in the modern sense: Take any two points on a surface. Those define a line. If that line does not lie evenly with (i.e. is not contained in) the surface, then the surface is not a plane surface.

Comment: So a plane surface does not have to be flat? It could be spherical and contain curved lines?

Comment: @seeker Lines do not curve. Curvature can be thought of as how far a _curve_ is from being a line. Lines form the _definition_ of straight.

Comment: Well according to Euclid's definition a line is a "breadthless" length, by this definition why can't a line be curved? He doesn't say all lines have to be "straight". In fact he lists a separate definition for "straight lines".

Comment: @seeker And here we get into why Euclid's axiomatized geometry was replaced in the 19th century by more precise axiomatic systems. It just isn't good enough once you get down into the gritty details.

Comment: Do you know of any resources that I can refer to that illuminate these definitions?

Comment: The lines in the original question above are explicitly straight lines, so there is no ambiguity there. Modern geometers usually assume all lines are straight lines; the kind that aren't straight are called "curves". So you should understand that if someone here says "line" they probably mean "straight line".

Comment: @seeker If you mean resources on the modern axiomatisations, then the two books I have seen recommended are Marvin Greenberg's "Euclidian and non-euclidian geometries" and Robin Hartshorne's "Geometry: Euclid and beyond". I myself have only looked at Greenberg, and it was a good and thurough tretment of the subject, along with some of the history of the developments in geometry, such as the numerous attempts to prove the parallel postulate from the others.

Comment: I disagree with you interpretation of "lies evenly..." I don't see why convexity should be related to planarity.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Do you mean that "surface $S$ lies evenly with line $l$" should not be interpreted as "$\forall x\in l(x\in S)$"?

Comment: Yes: I would take objects to lie evenly if they lie in the same plane. Anyway, since Euclid's lines are infinite this would limit you to convex unbounded surfaces, which seems extreme.

Comment: @KevinCarlson But intuitively, planar surfaces are exactly the ones that are unbounded and convex. That's what I'm trying to get to here. A sphere is not convex since the "Lines on itself" would be chords (extended to infinity), and the chords do not lie evenly with the sphere. However, for a plane in $\Bbb R^3$, any two points define a line which lies entirely in the plane.

Comment: Really, you don't think a disk is a planar surface? That doesn't match my intuitions-though requiring unboundedness is more plausible to me than convexity, which I still don't follow you on.

Answer (score -1):

In differential geometry a 2-D surface is like a sphere which has length and breadth, Gauss curvature K is non-zero. It is doubly curved.

A flat surface has zero K and is a part of a plane or developable to it, at least one of two radii of curvature is infinity.

If you try to flatten a Pringles saddle shaped chip, circumferential lines tend to overlap before they break up. On the other hand when you step on an egg shell crushing it, it splits the boundary circumferentially.

Such differential deformation behavior is at the back of intuitive physical perception of spatial embedding of positive, negative and zero double curvature of surfaces.. while engrossed in the formalism of their mathematical treatment.